# Array of object initialization

Tags: java, arrays

Alright. So i'm trying to initialize an array of object. The ID is the position of the array. But everytime i run this, it always takes the last entered ID as it's current (Whatever ID I take, it returns the last one entered). So here's the full code:

```
public class Main {
private static String answerString = "Start";
private static final double TPS = 0.05;
private static final double TVQ = 0.09975;
private static final int BILLET = 800;
private static double prixTotal;
public static int persNum;
private static int siege1 = 35;
private static int siege0 = 1;
private static double prixBilletAv, prixTPS, prixTVQ, prixBilletAp;
private static int answerInt;
public static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
public static Person[] pers = new Person[9999];


public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("Bienvenue à bord de SonicXpress!");
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("Loading. . .");

    for(int i = 0; i < 9999; i++){
        System.out.println("yo");
        pers[i] = new Person();
    }

    System.out.println("Done loading!");
    System.out.println("");
    while(!"Exit".equals(answerString))
        begin();
    }
public static void begin(){
    System.out.println("Que veux-tu faire? (Creer , Check , Total , Exit) : ");
    answerString = scan.next();

    if("Creer".equalsIgnoreCase(answerString)){
        createPers();
    }else{
        if("Check".equalsIgnoreCase(answerString)){
            checkPers();
        }else{
            if("Exit".equalsIgnoreCase(answerString)){
                System.out.println("Exiting");
                System.exit(0);
            }else{
                if("Total".equalsIgnoreCase(answerString)){
                    total();
                }else{
                    System.err.println("Bad value!");
                    System.exit(0);
                }    
            }
        }
    }
}
public static void createPers(){

    System.out.print("Entrez le numéro du client(ID) :\n");
    answerInt = scan.nextInt();

    persNum = answerInt;
    pers[persNum].setID(answerInt);

    System.out.print("Entrez le nom du client(name) : \n");
    answerString = scan.next();

    pers[persNum].setName(answerString);

    System.out.print("Entrez l'age du client : \n");
    answerInt = scan.nextInt();

    pers[persNum].setAge(answerInt);

    System.out.print("Entrez la classe (0 = première classe et 1 = classe touriste): \n");
    answerInt = scan.nextInt();

    pers[persNum].setClasse(answerInt);
    if(pers[persNum].getClasse() == 1){
        pers[persNum].setSiege(siege1);
        siege1 ++;
    }else{
        if(pers[persNum].getClasse() == 0){
           pers[persNum].setSiege(siege0);
           siege0++;
        }
    }
}

public static void checkPers(){
    System.out.print("Entrez le numéro du client ID : \n");
    answerInt = scan.nextInt();
    prixBilletAv = BILLET + 10;
    System.out.println(answerInt);
    persNum = answerInt;
    System.out.println(persNum);
    System.out.println("--- Réservation : ");
    System.out.println("Le nom du client est : " + pers[answerInt].getName());
    System.out.println("L'age du client est : " + pers[answerInt].getAge());
    System.out.println("La classe du client est : " + pers[answerInt].getClasse());
    System.out.println("Le numéro de siège du client est : " + pers[answerInt].getSiege());
        if (pers[persNum].getAge() < 12 || pers[answerInt].getAge() >= 60){
            prixBilletAv = BILLET - 50;
        }
        if (pers[persNum].getClasse() == 0){
            prixBilletAv = prixBilletAv + 100;
        }
        prixTVQ = prixBilletAv * TVQ ;
        prixBilletAp = prixBilletAv + prixTVQ;

        prixTPS = prixBilletAv * TPS;
        prixBilletAp = prixBilletAp + prixTPS;

        pers[persNum].setPrixBillet(prixBilletAp);

    System.out.println("Le cout du billet est : " + prixBilletAv);
    System.out.println("TPS : " + prixTPS);
    System.out.println("TVQ : " + prixTVQ);
    System.out.println("Montant à payer : " + pers[persNum].getPrixBillet());
}

public static void total(){
    for (int i = 0; i < 9999; i++){
        prixTotal = prixTotal + pers[i].getPrixBillet();
    }
    System.out.print("Montant total des billets vendus = " + prixTotal + "\n");
    System.out.println("-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
}
```

The problem is that whenever i try to check for a specific ID it gives me the last one entered. For exemple, if I `set Id = 1270`, `name = Joe`, `age = 43`, etc for object 1 and `ID = 1824`, `name = Bob`, `age = 24 for object 2, when I check, it will automatically output object 2 no matter what`ID` I put in.

And for the second class :

```
class Person {
private static int ID;
private static String name;
private static int age;
private static int classe;
private static double prixBillet;
private static int siege;

/**
 * @return the ID
 */
public static int getID() {
    return ID;
}

/**
 * @param aID the ID to set
 */
public static void setID(int aID) {
    ID = aID;
}

/**
 * @return the name
 */
public static String getName() {
    return name;
}

/**
 * @param aName the name to set
 */
public static void setName(String aName) {
    name = aName;
}

/**
 * @return the age
 */
public static int getAge() {
    return age;
}

/**
 * @param aAge the age to set
 */
public static void setAge(int aAge) {
    age = aAge;
}

/**
 * @return the classe
 */
public static int getClasse() {
    return classe;
}

/**
 * @param aClasse the classe to set
 */
public static void setClasse(int aClasse) {
    classe = aClasse;
}

/**
 * @return the prixBillet
 */
public static double getPrixBillet() {
    return prixBillet;
}

/**
 * @param aPrixBillet the prixBillet to set
 */
public static void setPrixBillet(double aPrixBillet) {
    prixBillet = aPrixBillet;
}

/**
 * @return the siege
 */
public static int getSiege() {
    return siege;
}

/**
 * @param aSiege the siege to set
 */
public static void setSiege(int aSiege) {
    siege = aSiege;
}
```

Thx in advance for your help :)

Comment: Your init code looks incomplete, but what's there is fine and pretty basic - it's just putting objects into the array. It might work better if you post more of your code...

Comment: I am a bit confused as well. When you say it gives you the last one entered do you mean: if you were to enter 5 for the variable "answerString" it would return 5 for the personID?

Comment: put the code for setID() method

Comment: make sure `id` is not `static`. And post code for `setID` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading through your code and your comments, I think I understand the problem. You don't seem to understand what `static` means, so let me brief you:

If a variable or method is `static` that means that [said variable] is not apart of ANY objects created of this [said class].
So, for example:

```
public class Test{
    public static int TestNum = 0;

    public static void setTestNum(int newNum){
        TestNum = newNum;
    }

    public static int getTestNum(){
        return TestNum;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        Test test1 = new Test();
        test1.setTestNum(5);

        Test test2 = new Test();
        System.out.println(test2.TestNum);
    }
}
```

The above example **will** output 5, because `TestNum` is a `static` variable. It is not a variable of the `test1` object, or of the `test2` object. It is a variable of the `class Test`. Does this make sense?

So, in your code you are repeatedly changing static variables, and whenever you reference any `Person` object, since all variables/methods are `static`, it references the variables of the class. This is why it seems like it is only referencing the most recent created `Person` object.

To fix this, you must simply get rid of the `static` in front of your methods. It might seem difficult at first to understand when a method/variable should be `static`, but over time it begins to make more and more sense as you work and become more experienced.

If I were you I'd also read through **[this](http://math.hws.edu/javanotes/c4/s2.html)** for a more in depth and eloquent explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
private static int ID;
```

to

```
private int ID;
```

If you make a variable `static` it means it belongs to the class. That is, there is only one `id` somewhere on the heap no matter how many objects you create. You are modifying the content of `id` every time and the last modification is what is preserved.

Change `setID` as shown below

```
public void setID(int aID) {
    this.ID = aID;
}
```

and `getID()` to

```
public int getID() {
   return this.ID;
}
```

Also, proper syntax to access any `static` member or method from inside the non static blocks is

```
className.staticMemberVariable
className.staticMethodName
```

If accessed from a `static` block, you need not to qualify the `static` field or method name with `classname`

for example, if `id` is static

```
public static void main (String...a) {
   //here just say id
   id = 5;
}
```

Comment: Nope didn't work it's still giving me the last object edited

Comment: Alright so I removed all of the static stuff on the getters and setters and it worked!